# What are the effects of long-term, mass-consumption of sugared, carbonated drinks and what can be done to stop?

Tags: diet, sugar, energy-drinks, caffeine

I am a *long-term*, *high-frequency* consumer of soft drinks specifically Coca-Cola and Pepsi.

In 2015 I am resolved to kick the habit once and for all but it is proving challenging.  My average daily consumption is between 2 and 2.5 litres (70-100 ounces).

A typical daily routine would be -

1. Awake
2. Strong coffee with 2 x sugar
3. 8am can of cola on the drive to work
4. 11am can of cola to prevent flagging/thirst
5. 12.30 can of cola with lunch
6. 3pm can of cola due to extreme drowsiness
7. Possibly 1,2 or even 3 cans of cola in the evening

I don't want to substitute the drinks for diet or lite or max versions.  I want to go as sugar-free as possible.

**What effects, both positive and negative, will I see in the immediate short term once I stop consuming these drinks and how can I best control the cravings?**

I feel like I concentrate better after consumption, my creativity and cognitive functions felt higher and more productive.  However I also find myself becoming more animated and talkative within meetings/around senior members of staff.

> Considerations

1. I have been tested for diabetes; I am clear but wish to remain that way
2. I am 32 years old with fairly sedentary job role (Agile ScrumMaster)
3. I am quite active; daily running and regular long distance hiking

Comment: Not a dupe but very similar: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/12901/how-do-i-stop-drinking-soda/12903#12903

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr - thank you for that.  Extremely useful answer.  I absolutely hate this addiction.

Comment: Don't stress about it. Sugar is a powerful additive. It will probably take a week or two before you get over it, but it can be done!

Comment: How is this related to fitness, other than "I move around"?

Comment: @JohnP it is diet related and directly related to achieving micro and macro nutritional goals.  Are we remove all dietary questions from SE?

Comment: @Venture2099 - Actually, yes, unless they relate to a fitness plan. That was decided a long time ago.

Comment: Do you have a Source for that decision?

Comment: @Venture2099 - Seriously? From the help center on questions you can ask: "nutrition as it relates to exercise", http://fitness.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic, http://meta.fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/287/should-title-be-fitness-instead-of-fitness-and-nutrition, http://meta.fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/306/fitness-and-nutrition-is-now-physical-fitness, http://meta.fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/560/why-are-nutrition-questions-off-limits, http://meta.fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/300/are-questions-specifically-about-nutrition-on-topic

Comment: I don't think you should expect new users to immediately visit the help centre to judge the validity of their question.  That's absurd; you should have raised this point properly as a comment instead the semi-arrogant way in which you did.

Comment: @Venture2099 - My mistake. I assumed, that since you have multiple stack exchange accounts, that you might have visited the "What topics" section of the help page. Mea culpa. Pardon me sir, but questions regarding nutrition are not considered on topic unless they relate to the benefit or detriment of your workout program. As it stands, your question is likely to be closed as off topic.

Comment: Better phrasing? :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19938/discussion-between-johnp-and-venture2099).

Comment: I am happy for it to be closed as per the SE.  I don't want to dilute the site with off-topics so please flag it accordingly.

Comment: If not already mentioned, the headache can be significant when reducing caffeine.

Answer (score 4):

> What effects, both positive and negative, will I see in the immediate short term once I stop consuming these drinks...

Positive:

- **You will probably lose weight.** Two litres of soda is about 800 Calories. For context, government agencies suggest the average person requires about 2000 Calories per day. So you are drinking nearly half of your require calorie intake in sugar beverages alone. If you only cut out soda, you would lose weight very quickly.

Negative:

- **You will become extremely irritable.** [Sugar is highly addictive](http://www.bbc.co.uk/science/0/21835302) and can [present withdrawal symptoms similar to of opioids](http://psycnet.apa.org/?fa=main.doiLanding&doi=10.1037/1064-1297.15.5.481).
- **Everything else will taste like crap.** [You are consuming nearly 200g](http://www.sugarstacks.com/beverages.htm) of sugar a day. Sugar is (or seems) delicious, nothing else will be as sweet to you as soda, so by comparison everything else will seem bland.
- **You will be less alert.** Sugar has strong effect on temporarily increasing alertness, [before leading to sluggishness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sugar_crash), which explains your 3pm soda.

> and how can I best control the cravings?

Through [focus and determination](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/12901/how-do-i-stop-drinking-soda/12903#12903) that is required when beating an addiction.

Answer (score 1):

I would pick one sugar or caffeine.  It is much more likely that you will fail if you if try to quit both at the same time.

To address the question of reducing the craving.

- Make a habit of drinking 1 cup of water first thing when you wake up in the morning (drink more water in general).    Dehydration is a contributing factor to fatigue.
- Calorie replacement.  70 to 100 oz. of soda has 800 to 1000 Calories in it.  You will need to replace these calories.  Put half and half in your coffee.  With this number of calories you could drink 3 cups of half or half or a can and a half coconut milk every day.
- Go caffeine free and get caught up on your sleep on the weekends.
- Regular exercise.